# Portfolio not showing in row

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

Please check this web page http://timelapseau.wpengine.com/our-portfolio/

All these project items are not showing in row. Help me to fix them.

Comment: add a working snippet or at least some code...

Comment: You can check code on url

Answer (score 0):

try this in your css:

```
.col-md-4.col-lg-4.col-sm-4.col-xs-6.project:nth-child(3n+4) {
  clear: both;
}
```

it resets the float for project-boxes with the index 4, 7, 11... 3n+4 But I think you better look at the content of your project-boxes and try to figure out which elements are using padding or margins that make a summ of 3 boxes greater then 100%